# Tomcat in my ec2 instance doesn't shut down or start properly

Tags: amazon-ec2, java-8, tomcat8

I have created a new t2.small instance where I setup tomcat8 with java 8. But this tomcat is causing issue when I shut it down and start, it sometimes starts properly, most of the times it either gets stuck at activating or deactivating and it take forever to start the tomcat. I don't understand why my other instances which were created a long time back work with no trouble but this gives me such a headache as both of them share similar configuration.

Please any solutions.

[image]

Comment: maybe the change in the public ip affects him?

Comment: There is insufficient detail for us to help you.  Please add the complete stacktrace(s) and other relevant formation from your Tomcat log files.  Cut and paste them as text rather than as images.  (Images are not searchable, and image links break.)